# I need to run a function when a cell changes value because of formula

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

Column D in my sheet contains a calculation of values in the row either by average, median, or mode based on user input. I need to run a function that will copy the formula's resulting value to a different spreadsheet each time the cell changes value. I have looked at onEdit() but don't understand it well. I won't be editing the cell directly. I don't want the cell to be copied if any cell in the row changes, only if the calculated value of that particular cell changes. Is this possible? Any help is appreciated greatly.

Column D contains:

```
=IFERROR(VLOOKUP(BU6,$A$106:$B$110,2,TRUE)," ")
```

BU6 contains: `=IFERROR(ARRAYFORMULA(IF(C6="Average",BR6,IF(C6="Median",BS6,IF(C6="Mode",BT6))))," ")`

A106:B110 contains:
[image: score values compaired to letter grades in a chart]

When Column D changes from (let's say) A to C, I want to copy that letter into a different spreadsheet.

Comment: You'll still use a triggered function, but would force checking that specific cell. The real question is what drives the value to change, i.e. how are the values that it calculates added or updated?

Comment: On each row, there are multiple places (columns H to BI) to enter values that will affect the D Column value. Changing one value on the row may or may not change Col D. Most likely it will take the change of 2 or more of those values before Col D changes. I suppose it would not hurt to write the same value over again on every change if there is not a better way. Thanks for your help so far.

Comment: you'll need to keep a record of the cells previous value, and each time the edit trigger fires, check if the values in a given row have changed, and if so, perform your desired action for that row.

Comment: I think that will solve my problem. Thank you!